# Firebase Custom reCaptach AuthUIDelegate - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

we wanted to present a custom SFSafariViewController to present the reCAPTCHA, it was given in the firebase docs to create a custom class that conforms to the FIRAuthUIDelegate protocol, and pass it to verifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:completion:.

I created a custom class that conforms to the protocol but the protocol needs us to pass a viewcontroller to it, but none of the details required to create that viewcontroller or any details or example as to how to use a custom viewcontroller is not given anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was asked but I had to attempt to do this over the last few days and couldn't find the answer in the documentation either.

The view controller passed to the protocol functions is not one that you can create yourself as it's provided by the Firebase SDK and it's some implementation of SFSafariViewController.

As long as you have set the delegate object on the call itself than the SDK will trigger the delegate object methods directly providing the View Controller.

The delegate is expected to be able to manage the layout of the controller and its own views so it will need some reference to a parent UIViewController.

You are limited to the customisation available for this class and its own views. I assume you could start manipulating the view hierarchy in the controller itself but as this was provided to me by Firebase I settled for just adding this on a view container in the parent.

You can add and remove the controller and view as a child controller as normal.